# Rav ovadia Yosef mishna berura

Tags: jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, hacham-ovadia-yosef

A rabbi recently told me that rav ovadia yosef has a "Mishna Berura" style commentary on the shulchan aruch. (I presume he wasn't referring to his son's work Halacha Berura.) anyone know what this work is if it exists?

Comment: As a follower of Hacham Ovadia Shali"a and a big fan of his and his sons works I can say with 100% certaintly that there is no book like this *published*. It is possible that he may be publishing a breif work on Shulhan Aruch in the near future called Maor Yisrael as he recently published Sefarim on the Gemara and Rambam in that style. It would seem that one on Shulhan Aruch would be the next in line.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is a Sefer called [Yalkut Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Yosef).

Comment: This wasn't actually written by Rav Ovadiah Yosef though.

Comment: The rabbi said the book was called "Mishna Berura"

Comment: @EfraimMatityahu, You can see [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3) a list of all R' Ovadiah's writings and the writings based on his teachings. There is nothing formally called "Mishna Berura". There is "Yalkut Yosef" mentioned above, there is "Halachah Berura", which you mentioned in the question, and there is "Livyat Chen", which is apparently on Hilchot Shabbat with a focus on the Mishna Berura.

Comment: Yalkut Yosef is not in the form of Mishna Berura and it is not written by Hacham Ovadia. Liwyat Hen is as Jake said above on Shulhan Aruch and the Mishna Berura on Hilchot Shabbat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are talking about his sefer Chazon Ovadia.

Comment: Welcome back Hacham, but Hazon Ovadia is the similar to the style of Yalkut Yosef. It's not on Shulhan Aruch per se. It's not even in the order of Maran.